# VueJS cannot use router inside store

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my logout action after clearing the auth data I want to route user to the home page.

```
logout({commit}){
      commit('clearAuthData')
      router.replace('/')
```

also I imported my routes.js file as this

```
 import router from './routes';
```

How do I use `router.replace` function inside my `store.js` file?

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/issues/171#issuecomment-298609471

Comment: I go through your link and still I can't understand this. Could you please explain me further.since I'm a Jr.Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass router as payload to the action.

for e.g. this is the component

```
<template>
    <button @click="logoutHandler">Log out</button>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["logout"]),
    logoutHandler() {
      this.logout({ router: this.$router });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

and in the action

```
logout({commit}, {router}){
      commit('clearAuthData')
      router.replace('/')
```

Comment: ...mapActions(["logout"]),
      onLogin () {
        console.log("INSIDE LOGIN FUNCTION");
        const formData = {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
          returnSecureToken:true
        }
        this.$store.dispatch('login',{
         email: formData.email,
         password: formData.password
        })
      console.log(formData)
    },
    onLogout(){
      //this.$store.dispatch('logout')
      this.logout({ router: this.$router });
    }
    }

Comment: now It says ReferenceError: mapActions is not  defined?

Comment: sorry. i forgot to add this `import { mapActions } from 'vuex'`. answer updated